# Similarity score with penalty if it doesn't match a specific part

Tags: neural-network, similarity, knn, cosine-similarity

I have been working with KNN, Fuzzy Matching, and Neural networks to do similarity scoring and have run into an interesting problem. We are using it to match drug formulations and I have found that matching them leads to false confidence in specific scenarios:

```
User Entered: oral Doxy 100mg tablet per tablet
Highest Similarity (False Positive): Amox 100mg per tablet oral tablet
True Positive:Doxycyline Hyclate 100 mg per tablet oral tablet
```

This is getting matched together because the 2nd part of the terms match, but the amox and doxy don't match. I have tried TF-IDF (with all the different hyper-parameters), CountVectorizer, and even boosting counts, but I have found it very hard to achieve even 75% accuracy.

Are there any known algorithms or maybe techniques to allow me to down-weight similarity if, for example, amox does not match in the 2nd form? I have the ability to identify the drug easily (amox vs doxy), but how to get that downweighting if amox is not in the network.  What I am trying to avoid is a requirement to scan through all formulations every time I try to find a match and create a custom filtering process where.  I was hoping to embed a penalty matrix of some sort into the matching.  The preference is to have a False Negative instead of a False Positive.

Comment: I believe that trying to solve such issue at ranking stage is not the best way to go. I would propose to do the following: 1) train NER that will map both "Doxy" and "Doxycyline" (or maybe even "Doxycyline Hyclate") to the same entity + put a flag on this entity that this is an "entity:drug"; 2) require that your search engine returns only those results which contain all the "entity:drug"s from the query.